# Execute action after pressing the keyboard

Tags: jquery, keydown

I need that when the user presses the DOWN button (down) on the keyboard, it goes to a div in the same way as with a scrollTop. Has anyone done something like this using jQuery?

It would be something like this?

```
$(window).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which != 40) return false;
    var posicao = $('.homeBaixoRodapeTexto1').position().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: posicao
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: `e.which = 40` should be  `e.which === 40` for starters. What you're doing now is just assigning e.which to 40 which will always be true, which would always cause this to return false.

Comment: A newbie question, this value '40' is the number of pixels?

Comment: The number 40 is the keycode of the key you're interested in. You should look up a reference for common keycodes like 13 (enter), 10 (tab), etc.

Comment: So, this is the correct syntax? `if (e.which !=== 40) return false;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `.offset().top` instead of `.position().top`.

```
$(window).on('keydown', function (e) {

    if (e.which != 40) return true;

    e.preventDefault();

    var posicao = $('.homeBaixoRodapeTexto1').offset().top;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: posicao
    }, 1500);

});
```

You have to be real careful with this. You're essentially breaking navigation with the keyboard.

Here's a small demo: http://jsbin.com/xecapoyu/3/edit?js,output